# Error to get data

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php $all_users = get_data('SELECT active FROM members WHERE active = 'Yes';'); $get_users = count($all_users); echo $get_users ;?>
```

I people, I have the follow error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Yes' (T_STRING) in

and I don't understand why, for me it's right..

Comment: @Dagon Do you mean, it's the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get_data('SELECT active FROM members WHERE active = "yes" ');
```

or

```
get_data('SELECT active FROM members WHERE active = \'Yes\' ');
```

or

```
get_data("SELECT active FROM members WHERE active = 'Yes' ");
```